# I would like to find the difference of each row, from the first row As Alias

Tags: mysql

To clarify my Title

I would like to tabulate how far behind the leader, each successive finisher is from 1st place as shown in my table below.

```
Finish | Points | Points Behind
   1   |  102   |
   2   |   92   |   10
   3   |   82   |   20
   4   |   71   |   31
   5   |   61   |   41
   6   |   50   |   52
   7   |   40   |   62
   8   |   30   |   72
   9   |   20   |   82
  10   |   10   |   92

 Select
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.Finish,
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.Points,
  some code I don't know As 'Points Behind'
 From
  snpc_stats.gamedetail
 Where
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.GamesID = 113
```

Comment: What happens when you have ties?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the points from `first finish` and do a `cross join` with rest of the table.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e088a/3)**

```
select  gd.Finish, gd.Points, 
        t.Points-gd.Points as PointsBehind
from gamedetail gd
cross join ( select max(Points) from gamedetail where Finish =1) t
```

Comment: I would suggest `max(Points)` or `limit 1` in case there are ties.